# Point from three circle chords

Tags: geometry, vectors

For $i=1,2,3$, let $C_i$ be the circle in the $xy$ plane with center $\mathbf{c}_i = (x_i,y_i)$ and radius $r_i$. Assume that these three circles all intersect one another (6 intersection points, in all). Then let $L_{ij}$ be the line through the intersection points of the circles $C_i$ and $C_j$; in other words, a common chord of both $C_i$ and $C_j$.

I think it's true that the three lines $L_{12}$, $L_{23}$ and $L_{31}$ all meet at a common point. Let's call this point $\mathbf{p}$. It's shown as a hollow (white) point in this picture:
[image]

Because of the symmetry of the situation, there must be some nice tidy symmetric coordinate-free expression that gives $\mathbf{p}$ in terms of $\mathbf{c}_1$, $\mathbf{c}_2$, $\mathbf{c}_3$. Presumably it will take the form
$$
\mathbf{p} = \lambda_1\mathbf{c}_1 + \lambda_2\mathbf{c}_2 + \lambda_3\mathbf{c}_3
$$
for some scalars $\lambda_1$, $\lambda_2$, $\lambda_3$ with $\lambda_1 + \lambda_2+\lambda_3 = 1$. What is this expression? In other words, what are $\lambda_1$, $\lambda_2$, $\lambda_3$?

What have I tried, some of you will surely ask. Well, I set up a coordinate system with origin at $\mathbf{c}_1$, and with $x$-axis passing through the point $\mathbf{c}_2$. It's not too hard to figure out the coordinates of $\mathbf{p}$ in this coordinate system. But the answer is messy, assymmetrical, and coordinate-system-dependent. I'm looking for something prettier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll change-up your notation a bit, centering circles at $A$, $B$, $C$ with respective radii $r$, $s$, $t$.

It is not too difficult to show that your point, call it $P$, is given by
$$P = \frac{1}{4|\triangle ABC|}\left(\;(|A|^2-r^2)(B-C)^\perp+(|B|^2-s^2)(C-A)^\perp+(|C|^2-t^2)(A-B)^\perp\;\right)$$
where $(x,y)^\perp := (y,-x)$, and where $|\triangle ABC|$ is the *signed* area of $\triangle ABC$ (positive when $A\to B\to C\to A$ traces the triangle counter-clockwise).

Then, while it is not particularly easy to *derive*, it is relatively straightforward (if tedious) to *verify*, that
$$P = \alpha A + \beta B + \gamma C$$
where
$$\begin{align}
\alpha &:= \frac{a}{8|\triangle ABC|^2} \left(\; a b c \cos A - r^2 a + s^2 b \cos C + t^2 c \cos B \;\right) \\[6pt]
\beta &:= \frac{b}{8|\triangle ABC|^2} \left(\; a b c \cos B - s^2 b + t^2 c \cos A + r^2 a \cos C \;\right) \\[6pt]
\gamma &:= \frac{c}{8|\triangle ABC|^2} \left(\; a b c \cos C - t^2 c + r^2 a \cos B + s^2 b \cos A \;\right)
\end{align}$$
and $\alpha + \beta + \gamma = 1$.

**Note.** The $a$, $b$, $c$ and $\cos A$, $\cos B$, $\cos C$ in the formulas refer to the sides and angles of $\triangle ABC$, not the lengths and directions of coordinate vectors $A$, $B$, $C$.

**Note.** When $r=s=t$, the above reduces to 
$$
\alpha = \frac{a^2 b c \cos A}{8|\triangle ABC|^2} \qquad
\beta  = \frac{a b^2 c \cos B}{8|\triangle ABC|^2} \qquad
\gamma = \frac{a b c^2 \cos C}{8|\triangle ABC|^2}$$

Comment: Thanks very much. The terms $|A|$, $|B|$, $|C|$ in the first expression for $P$ seem odd. These terms only make sense if you have an identified origin, and it seems to me that $P$ should be independent of any choice of origin.

Comment: Did you try removing the angles $A$, $B$, $C$ from the formulae for $\alpha$, $\beta$, $\gamma$? I was thinking I could get Mathematica to do this, and try to simplify. But, if you have already tried that, then I won't bother.

Comment: I found out that the point $P$ has a name. It's called the radical center, or the power center of the three circles. Each chord is a special case of the radical axis of two circles.

Comment: @bubba: Yes, the first formula gives $P$'s Cartesian coordinates according to some fixed origin that defines the coordinates of points $A$, $B$, $C$. (Apropos of your later comment, it's interesting that, for instance, $|A|^2-r^2$ is the *power* of the origin with respect to $\bigcirc A$.) Finding that was preliminary to determining the $(\alpha, \beta, \gamma )$ representation, which gives the origin-independent [Barycentric coordinates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barycentric_coordinate_system) of $P$ relative to the triangle.

Comment: @bubba: Of course, you can "remove" $\cos A$, $\cos B$, $\cos C$, by re-writing them in terms of $a$, $b$, $c$ via the Law of Cosines, but I don't know if this is what you meant.

Comment: yes, that's what I meant. I tried it myself, and it didn't help, really. Formulae that involve only $a,b,c$ are "nice" in some sense, but they are more complex than the  ones you gave.

Comment: I was hoping for simpler expressions, but, after quite a bit of trying, I can't find any, and apparently no-one else can, either, so I accepted this answer. Thanks again.

Comment: They may be about as simple as they're gonna get. However, since $a=b \cos C + c \cos B$, you *could* write the big factor of $\alpha$ as $$a b c \cos A + ( t^2-r^2 ) c \cos B + ( s^2 - r^2 ) b \cos C$$ which may-or-may-not count as an improvement. The best cosine-less forms I've found:
$$\begin{align}
\alpha &= \frac{a^2(-a^2+b^2+c^2)+(t^2-r^2)(a^2-b^2+c^2)+(s^2-r^2)(a^2+b^2-c^2)}
{16|\triangle ABC|^2} \\[4pt]
&= \frac{a^2(-a^2+b^2+c^2-2r^2)+t^2(a^2-b^2+c^2)+s^2(a^2+b^2-c^2)}
{16|\triangle ABC|^2}
\end{align}$$ Yuck ... but at least the denominators become: $$(a+b+c)(-a+b+c)(a-b+c)(a+b-c)$$

Comment: I should also point out that in the $r=s=t$ case, since the Law of Sines gives us, for circumdiameter $d$, $$a = d\sin A \qquad b = d \sin B \qquad c = d \sin C$$ we have $$\alpha = \frac{\cos A}{2\sin B\sin C} = \frac{-\cos(B+C)}{2\sin B\sin C} = \frac12\left(1-\cot B\cot C\right)$$ This reduces the number of elements in the computation from five (three lengths, a cosine, and an area) to just two (cotangents); I'd call that progress. :)

Comment: Thanks. The triangle professionals always seem to gravitate towards formulae that involve cotangents. See Kimberling's Encyclopedia of Triangle Centers. He lists about 5000 triangle centers, but, oddly, the radical center is not one of them. Anyway, I tried working cotangents into the formulae, but it didn't help. As you say, maybe this is as good as it gets.